# Does NLTK have a tool for tagging for animate versus inanimate?

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am trying to tag a list of words for [animacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animacy). I've tried using SpaCy and Stanford Core NLP, but these seem only to tag for named entities.

I know that Stanford has an animacy dictionary, but I don't know how to use it and I can't find any good instructions.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in NLTK. [This](http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/bowman-chopra-srw-preprint.pdf) paper from the Stanford NLP group might get you further, though.